# How to black out a Swing component?

Tags: java, swing

Hi have a requirement where on some condition I have to black out the swing component(Text Field) preserving its string value. ie the component should not show what string value it holds.

Comment: not found yet, tried to make it invisible but I want the filed to be present but shouldn't show the data.

Answer (score 4):

There is `JPasswordField`, which is a text field that can be toggled to show **** (or some other echo character) instead of the actual content.  That is probably the easiest way.

If that isn't good enough, you could pull the content and store it externally, blank or blot or whatever the field, and `setEnabled(false)` on it.  When you enable the field again, put the content back.  If it's necessary to use `getText()` in the meantime, you'll have to override that so you can substitute the stored content when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

To make entire text black call

```
textfield.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0,0))
textfield.setBackground(Color.BLACK)
textfield.setOpaque(true)
```

to prevent them from selecting the text call

```
textfield.setFocusable(false)
```

Comment: Though a good suggestion, but why not we use this , `textField.setForeground(textField.getBackground());`, this will be done without any headaches :-)

Comment: @GuruKulki and Garrett: Consider also setting the text field's focusable property to `false` when doing this as well. Otherwise the text will show when the field has focus and the text is selected. 1+ vote for your good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [JLayer Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html):

[image: An example of gradient in front of JPanel]

Answer (score 2):

You should hide the text field using `.setVisible(false)`, and replace it by a different component which is black (e.g. a `JLabel` with a black background). This can be done by putting both components (The label and the text field) in a dedicated `JPanel`, stacking them over each other. You can optionally just simply hide the text field, if you don't need to have a black area there instead.

There are other methods for doing this involving only the text field, but none of them are fool-proof, because different operating systems will render Swing components differently (esp. Mac OS X), so overriding the text field's `paint()` method or changing the text color (as described by @GarrettHall) would not always work, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to remove the component from its container and replace it with a dummy component of the same type.
This could be nicely encapsulated by creating your own component that encapsulates swapping the components (skeleton):

```
public class BlackOutTextField extends JPanel {

    private final JTextField realField = new JTextField();
    private final JTextField dummyField = new JTextField();
    private boolean isBlackedOut;

    {
        dummyField.setEditable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(realField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return isBlackedOut ? "" : realField.getText();
    }

    public void setText(final String text) {
        if (!isBlackedOut)
            realField.setText(text);
    }

    public void setBlackedOut(final boolean blackedOut) {
         if (this.isBlackedOut != blackedOut) {
             this.isBlackedOut = blackedOut;
             removeAll();
             add(this.isBlackedOut ? dummyField : realField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
             revalidate();
         }
    }
}
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small example that just makes the characters black and the textbox black too, using **Only** JTextField, as you asked.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RunnableTest{    
    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
        textfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,30));
        textfield.setForeground(Color.black);
        textfield.setBackground(Color.black);
        textfield.setSelectedTextColor(Color.black);
        textfield.setSelectionColor(Color.black);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(textfield);
        frame.pack();

         frame.setVisible(true);    
    } 
}
```

this method `textfield.setForeground(Color.black);` sets the font to black, and `textfield.setBackground(Color.black);` this other method sets the background to black. and

```
textfield.setSelectedTextColor(Color.black);
textfield.setSelectionColor(Color.black);
```

sets the selection black so that you cannot see what was selected.

Of course, you can use the password field as an alternative, if you do not want to use JTextField, and prevent the user from copying the text.

EDIT: if you do not want the user to copy text using CTRL+C add a keyadapter to the textfield so that you know when the user pressed both keys at the same moment. of course, there are many other combinations on other systems, but that is not the question.

Comment: You can still CTRL-C the text :)

Comment: Of course you can, its a JTextField. and the user did not specify you did not have to. it does not show the value.

Comment: Ahha, this is amazing, I almost forgot about setting, `SelectionColours` while commenting, +1, for this nice addition :-), though what is stated by @Durandal , that gives only one option the `JPasswordField` :-)

Comment: yes, i had not added it but then i saw i could see the selected text, thank you.

Comment: Very many operating systems do not use [Ctrl]+[C] for copying text. Some alternatives are [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[C] (Unix), [Command]+[C] (Mac OS X), [Ctrl]+[Insert] (Windows and CUA-compatible systems), or middle-clicking on the text (X-windows).

Comment: Yes, i agree, but **But thats not what the user asked** it was an addition.